# Popup appears when clicking between the Newest badge and Next badge

Tags: bug, badges, badge-progress

I found a minor issue on the badge tracker of my user profile when I click exactly besides the newest badge which I have earned. When I click on the badge it opens the popup view with badge details, but when I click between the "Newest" badge section and the "Next badge" section the popup also appears, which is incorrect.

[image]

Comment: I can confirm it is still the case in Chrome at least.

Answer (score 3):

This looks to have been fixed, perhaps with the [New responsive Activity page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/372049/295232). The space between the newest badge and the progress bar has been reduced, but the badge popup is only shown when clicking on the newest badge itself, as it should.

[image]